# prevent activity from receiving touch events when screen display is off

Tags: android, focus, touch-event, android-windowmanager

I'm setting my screen to be always awake in order to preventing it from going into sleep mode at all.

hence, when the screen display is turned off, the user has to touch the screen in order to bring it on again, but the problem is that this touch is received by the foreground activity and it reacts according to it, and the user is for sure just trying to turn the screen display on.

I tried to set the following flags but didn't work:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
```

&&

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

To resolve your issue you have to do one of the below things which prevents screen to turn off automatically.

Add `android:keepScreenOn="true"` to some widget in your layout XML resource for this activity. So long as that widget is visible on the screen, the screen will not turn off automatically.

**OR**

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

to disable the screen timeout and

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

to re-enable it.

Comment: I don't want to keep the screen on, as I said I want it to goes in the stand-by mode which will turn off the display but don't go to the sleep mode which will turn off the cpu, hence, I don't want to keep the display on all the time.